# Jasmine/Protractor wait for assertion to be correct before logging as error

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor, karma-jasmine, e2e-testing

I'm using Protractors [ExpectedConditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) to prevent early assertion my e2e tests. I'm looking for an easier way of doing this:

```
it('should wait for an element to be visible before assertion', () => {
    const myElem = element(by.className('myElem'));

    browser.get('/myComponent');
    browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(myElem), 5000);
    expect(myElem.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

What I would like to have is an assertion that combines my two last lines as they basically do the same thing (kinda... not really... but kinda).

It just feels bad doing it this way.

What I would want would look something like this:

```
    expect(myElem.isPresent()).wait(5000).toBeTruthy();
```

Just as browser.wait it should wait or return earlier if the condition turns truthy.

Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this or a similarly simple solution?

PS:
browser.waitForAngular() turns out to be unreliable for my purposes. And (in addition) is still too much code.

I was thinking about adding a jasmine matcher as explained [here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/upgrading.html), but a matcher can't handle this requirement IMHO.

Comment: If `browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(myElem),5000);` fails, it will output **Failed: Wait timed out after 5000ms**. This isn't same syntax as an expect, but it will let you know that the element did not appear

Answer (score 0):

By looking at code it looks like you are not considering the async nature of javascript. I would request you to try below code. This will work for you.

```
it('should wait for an element to be visible before assertion', () => {
        const myElem = element(by.className('myElem'));

        browser.get('/myComponent').then(()=> {
        return browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(myElem), 5000);
}).then(()=> {
        expect(myElem.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
});
    });
```

Comment: this is not true. As jasmine uses the control flow system ( https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md ). We don't have to use .then, as the promises are evaluated async anyway. Furthermore, the code works. I just don't like doing the same thing (kinda) twice. Looks like a bad pattern.

Comment: If all the actions are returning protractor promise(protractor actions) then control flow is usefull. But if you are adding your function which is returning promise then control flow will not take care of it.